# Kartik's star-rating widget: Plugin Methods

Tags: yii2

INTRODUCTION:

1. I have a blog maked on Yii2. The widget used for making rating is:
   http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/star-rating#basic-usage
   http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating#installation
2. Each **post** from blog have his **AVERAGE RATING** that is read from *database*.
3. After the user selects his own rating - **segregate rating**, the **AVERAGE RATING** is calculated in RatingController and recorded in *database*.

QUESTION:

How dynamically show the new calculated rating (**AVERAGE RATING**) after the user clicked on the star? Now for exemple (exemple with 2 voters) if the average rating is 4.5 and the user chooses for exemple 3.5, then after that it shows **3.5** instead 4. If updating page than it's ok, it shows **4**. How to apply "Plugin Methods"?, for example 'update' or 'refresh'?

Comment: add your current code and then we will sort out what should be exactly done , always show your efforts in form of your code to avoid downvotes, and how are you updating the rating in database once you click on the star

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the concept is simple if you concentrate you have to update the ratings as soon as you click on the star and then you want to update the rating you need to use the plugin `events` and `methods` provided namely `rating:change` and `update`, use the `rating:change` to detect the click and make an `ajax` `post` request to the `controller/action` to update the rating in database ,and then send back the new rating as the response, then in the ajax `success` function update the star rating plugin with the new rating.

I will add the code that would emphasize the main logic rather than calculating the average.

Your star rating input code will look like the following look into the `success` function to see how to call the `update` method of `starrating`.

```
echo $formReview->field ( $review , 'rate' , [ 'inputOptions' =>
    [ 'class' => 'form-control' ] ] )->widget ( StarRating::classname () , [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'step' => 0.50 ,
        'showClear' => true ,
        'showCaption' => true ,
        'filledStar' => '<i class="zmdi zmdi-star"></i>' ,
        'emptyStar' => '<i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i>' ,
    ] ,
    'pluginEvents' => [
        'rating:change' => "function(event, value, caption){
            $.ajax({
                url:'path/to/update-rating',
                method:'post',
                data:{rate:value},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                    $(event.currentTarget).rating('update',data.rating);
                }
            });
        }"
    ]
] )->label ( false );
```

in your `controller/action`

```
   public function actionUpdateRating() {

        $response['success'] = false;

        if ( Yii::$app->request->post () ) {

            $id = Yii::$app->request->post ( 'blog_id' );
            $model = Blog::findOne ( $id );

            //update your database with the new rating 
            //............
            //get new rating in $newRating

            $response['rating'] = $newRating;
            $response['success'] = true;
        }
        echo Json::encode ( $response );
        Yii::$app->end ();
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, ist's working!
But i have a question: why is it used "Yii::$app->end ();", and it is obligatory?